# Is a weapon with higher min/max damage better than a higher DPS for Demon Hunters?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I've read that for a demon hunter the weapon with the higher min/max dmg is better than the weapon with higher DPS but lower min/max dmg:

> This is why most people will see the best increase of pure damage based on the min and max damage of your weapon. Remember the dps stat is just to give you an idea of how good a weapon is, but it is not as important as the min – max damage of the weapon.
>   <sub>- [Source](http://competitiveguides.com/diablo-3-class-guides/demon-hunter-stats-guide/)</sub>

Is this true? Because the DPS number from the character screen proves it wrong.

Comment: Giving a quick lookover of that site, it's got some calculation errors, and is pretty wrong about the DPS stat.  DPS takes min/max damage on the weapon into account.  It doesn't take primary stat, but that guide doesn't mention that at all.

Comment: Who are the "pros" behind that site? It's very poorly written and seems entirely dedicated to selling the strategy guide ... this is definitely not a source you want to be going with.

Comment: while many skills take only the weapon damage (i.e. min/max) into account, there are often offset by attack speed so two characters with different APS but similar DPS will often output the same damage.

Comment: Oh, and that guide is horribly out of date as 1.03 patch is a long long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends greatly on what you are wanting to accomplish. The "DPS" that is shown on the weapon is calculated based on the min, max, attacks per second and other damage modifiers on the weapon.

That is strictly a DPS value.

When you are looking at abilities and they say:

> Does X% weapon damage.

That means it will do X% of your weapon damage. Your weapon damage is calculated based on the min, max, primary attribute and a few other modifiers. The key is, Attack speed is not used for this calculation.

When you are trying to figure out how much damage a specific ability will do, the "Damage" that you see on your character sheet is not the correct value you should be using. "Damage" on the character sheet is actually DPS with tons of other variables.

For builds that focus on burst damage, high min-max weapons are good. Because your initial hits are going to hit even harder.

For any thing else, you just need to make a decision based on the skills you are using, your "on hit" abilities, primary resource regeneration... etc. This decision is very build and gear dependent.

Answer (score -1):

as playing a demon hunter myself mostly i cannot say this is true.
the skills are also based on your attack speed.
so in the end it all evens out.
however a higher min max would usually also mean that the weapon speed is slower , what would mean that you can do more damage with given amount of hatred.

also what you might consider is my rule of thumb;
try it out for yourself.
Take 2 weps with same dps but different speeds and do a run with both and time it.

i myself only pay attention to dps.